# Distance between polynomials in euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In Euclidean space $R[x]_{\leq n}$consisting of polynomials with scalar product i need to find distance between polynomial $f=2$ and subspace of polynomials with zero constant term.

How can i approach to this problem?

Comment: Did you mean a polynomial of degree 2? Or the constant 2?

Comment: If $f = 2$ denotes the constant polynomial $2$, then it belongs to the subspace mentioned. So, I think the distance from the subspace is $0$.

Comment: Remark: the 'subspace of polynomials with non zero constant term' is not a subspace

Comment: @twnly, constant

Comment: @CharlesMadeline, yes, sorry, i edited. With zero constant term

Comment: Given a subspace $U$ and element $v$ of the vector space $W$ not in $U$, the distance of $v$ from $U$ is the length of $v-t$, with $t\in U$ chosen so each $s\in U$ satisfies $(s-t)\cdot (t-u)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If your inner product is defined by $\langle p,q \rangle=\int_0^{1} p(x)q(x)dx$ then the answer is $2$. To see this let $f_n(x)=2n(\frac 1 n -x)$ for $x <\frac 1 n$ and $0$ otherwise. it is easy to see that the distance between $f_n$ and $2$ tends to $2$. Now Weirstrass approximation shows that required distance is also $2$.  [Some details:  the distance is obviously $\leq 2$ so we only have to produce some sequence in the subspace whose distance to $2$ tends to $2$. By Weirstrass approximation any continuous function vanishing at $0$  can be approximated uniformly by polynomials vanishing at $0$ and I am using this for $f_n$].